# How to make it so when I press load game it not only loads the information but brings you into the game in that state?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I am making a game and want the load button to bring the player back into the game where it was saved using shared preferences. Is there perhaps something the load method is missing? The load method and button are in a different activity in the main menu but you can go back using the menu button

```java
public static final String MY_PREFS = "prefs";
public static final String POSITION = "position";
public static final String INVENTORY = "inventory";
SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;

SaveButton = findViewById(R.id.SaveButton);
SaveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        saveData();
    }
});

MenuButton = findViewById(R.id.MenuButton);
MenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        finish();
    }
});

} //  public void setupControls()

public void saveData() {

    sharedPrefs = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor edit = sharedPrefs.edit();
    edit.putInt(POSITION, thePlayer.getPlayerPos());
    edit.putString(INVENTORY, thePlayer.getInventory());
    edit.commit();

    Toast.makeText(this, "Data Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

//The code below here is in a different activity

loadGame_button = findViewById(R.id.loadGame_button);
loadGame_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        loadData();
    }
});

public void loadData() {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(MY_PREFS, MODE_PRIVATE);
    inv = sharedPreferences.getString(INVENTORY, "");
    pos = sharedPreferences.getInt(POSITION, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: split your game into various states in draw(): `mainmenu`, `game` `pausemenu`, `gameoverscreen`. Set your load button in any state which isn't `game`, and make it so besides loading your info, will also switch the state to `game`.

Comment: The load button is already in the main menu activity while the save button is in the game activity if that's what you're saying? Where would draw(): be?
I'm not sure I follow properly, sorry, I'm not too proficient.

Comment: I'm saying that the load button should load the game activity along with the info. But I don't know how to load an activity from another activity. And draw() would be where the game functions are being executed.

Comment: Well also in the main menu activity it has "new game" which produces a new game for the player
`newGame_button = findViewById(R.id.newGame_button);
        newGame_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);`
But I wouldn't know how to make it so it goes into a saved one